# heap corruption when using free()

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, free, dynamic-allocation

I am new to dynamic allocation in c and I am getting heap corruption error at the call of the `free()` function.

The whole code is supposed to simulate the reallocation function `realloc()`and it works fine until the end. I ran the code multiple times in debugger mode step by step and the error appears at the end. If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void realocare(int **v, int n,int m)
{
    int *aux;
    unsigned int i;

    aux = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        aux[i] = v[i];

    *v = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        v[i] = aux[i];
    free(aux);
}

void afisare(int *v, int n,int i)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf_s("%d ", v[i]);

        printf_s("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int *v;
    unsigned int n,i,m;

    scanf_s("%u", &n);

    v = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &v[i]);

    m = n;
    printf("%d", m);
    afisare(v, n, i);
    n++;
    realocare(&v, n,m);
    v[n - 1] = 9000;
    afisare(v, n, i);

    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Hint: look at `realocare(v, n,m);`

Comment: at `realocare` : `v = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` : It does not change the variable on the caller side.

Comment: Even if `realocare()` didn't risk writing out of bounds (described in @alk's answer), it doesn't really do anything except leak memory.

Comment: OT: All those casts to `malloc()` are useless in C. Just drop them.

Comment: `*v = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` is a memory leak. You are losing the old `*v` pointer without freeing it first.  You want a `free(*v)` before this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate to `v` `n` elements

```
v = ... malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

and assign `m`

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    v[i] = aux[i];
```

For the case that `m` is larger then `n`: Doing so writes to invalid memory, and with this invokes undefined behaviour, so anything can happen from this moment on.

In your particulate case most likely this messes up internal memory management structures, causing the failure a later call to `free()`.

---

Changes done to a variable which had been passed to a function are *not* reflected by the caller, as the function in C always and ever just receives a copy of what the caller passed down.

So, for example the new value you assigned to `v` stays *unknown* to the caller of `realocare()`.

You can fix this by adjusting the code as follows:

```
void realocare(int **ppv, int n, int m)  //reallocation simulation function
{
  int *aux;
  unsigned int i;

  aux = malloc(m*sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    aux[i] = (*ppv)[i];

  free(*ppv); // Free what you had, to not leak this memory.

  *ppv = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    (*ppv)[i] = aux[i];

  free(aux);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
realocare(&v, n, m);
```

---

Your code uses two calls to `malloc()` and two calls to `free()`. This is inefficient.

Look at the following (adding some other not just cosmetic changes):

```
void realocare(int **ppv, size_t n, size_t m)  // no need for negative sizes ...
{
  int * aux = malloc(n * sizeof *aux);
  size_t i = 0; // no need for negative counters ...

  for (;i < m; ++i)
  {
    aux[i] = (*ppv)[i];
  }

  free(*ppv); 

  *ppv = aux;
}
```

Just one `malloc` and one `free`... :-)

---

And for completeness a robust version:

```
int realocare(int **ppv, size_t n, size_t m)  
{
  int result = -1; // be pessimistic

  if (NULL == ppv)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    int * aux = malloc(n * sizeof *aux);

    if (NULL != aux) 
    {
      size_t i = 0; 

      for (;i < m; ++i)
      {
        aux[i] = (*ppv)[i];
      }

      free(*ppv); 

      *ppv = aux;

      result = 0;  // return success! 
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>  // for errno

...

int main(void)
{
  ...

  if (-1 == realocare(&v, n, m))
  {
    perror("realocare() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

Comment: thanks but im not sure if i figured it out, i made the following changes but it still doesn't work: 'void realocare(int ***v, int n,int m)', '*v = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));  ' realocare(&v, n,m);'

Comment: @rednefed: You are welcome. For fun I added a stripped own version of your code.